# json-c: Format new double object type?

Tags: c, json, linux, types, json-c

I use the json-c lib to create a json-formated string. I have some float values and json-c does some conversion to double which leads to some errors:

```
float nachtmodusfaktor;
nachtmodusfaktor = 0.8;

json_object_object_add(jsons[8],"nachtmodusfaktor",json_object_new_double(round(nachtmodusfaktor * 10) / 10));
```

The result in the json string is:

```
     "nachtmodusfaktor": 0.80000000000000004,
```

It does not matter if I do the round() call or not. In both cases there are these glitches.

Is there a way to tell the json-c library to put the object in a defined format just with printf (ie `"%5.2f"`) which then would show `0.80` instead of the above?

Or do you have an idea for a workaround?

Thanks!

/KNEBB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly why the function `json_object_new_double_s` exists:

from [doc](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.12/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#a50c188c8eb9007f05ab1aa0e22eae90c)

> Create a new json_object of type json_type_double, using the exact serialized representation of the value.
>
> **This allows for numbers that would otherwise get displayed inefficiently (e.g. 12.3 => "12.300000000000001")** to be serialized with the more convenient form.

`json_object_new_double(round(nachtmodusfaktor * 10) / 10);` should be replaced by:

```c
   char buffer[8];
   sprintf(buffer, "%f", nachtmodusfaktor);
   json_object_new_double_s(nachtmodusfaktor, buffer);
```

Comment: Hi, 
thanks. It is indeed working.

Though it is quite complicated. Anyways, working.

Thanks for pointing it out!
/KNEBB